# Ruby on rails Issue with mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

hello I' am new at ruby on rails and I am trying to implement an email sender.  I would like the email sender to send an email every time somebody types their email. But is not working for some reason, please help me.

```
 class ZipMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: "Example@gmail.com"
    def zip_email_confirmation(zip_mailer)
       recipents zip_mailer
       from    "Example@gmail.com"
       subject "Thanks from Example"
       body     :zip_mailer => zip_mailer
    end
 end              

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address              =>"smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 =>587,
    :domain               =>"gmail.com",
    :user_name            =>"gmail",
    :password             =>"12345",
    :authentication       =>"plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}





 def create
    @box = Box.new(box_params)
    #TO DO: validations. return errors or save
    if @box.save
       ZipMailer.zip_email_confirmation(@zip_mailer).deliver
       ConfirmMailer.box_alert(@box).deliver
       session[:box_id] = @box.id
       render 'charges/new'

    else
      render action: 'new'
    end   



<%= form_tag do %>
<%= email_field(:zip_mailer, :address) %>

 <%= submit_tag("sub") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what is not working, can you show the logs?  what is ConfirmMailer?

Comment: Can you be more specific with what is not working? At what point does this fail? Does it fail with a specific error message? There are a battery of reasons why an email message might not be sent, many of which are external to your code.